# get child notes without dataset. dataset designer

Tags: c#, sql-server, datarow, dataset-designer

I used the dataset designer to access the database.
And I do not understand why I'm getting no data.

Please tell me how to fix that

```
usersTableAdapter usersTA = new usersTableAdapter();
var usersTable = new users.usersDataTable();
usersTA.Fill(usersTable);

partnersTableAdapter partnersTA = new partnersTableAdapter();
var partnersTable = new users.partnersDataTable();
partnersTA.Fill(partnersTable);

VK_BDayParser.users.usersRow row = usersTable.FindByid(currentItem.id);
var partners = row.GetpartnersRows();
```

**partners** is always zero-lenghted array, but in the database table **partners** has many rows

Comment: Have you debugged `usersTable` after `usersTA.Fill(usersTable);` to check that it actually contains data?

Comment: @BerndLinde yes, it contains data. I normally add or change data in the table users, it just did not copy the code in question.

Comment: And you have debugged to check that `usersTable` contains atleast one row with the `id` in `currentItem.id`?

Comment: @BerndLinde Look, i have information in row... http://puu.sh/fZiFM/a781e0a12a.jpg

Comment: There is no direct link between your populated `usersTable` and the `partnersTable`. They are two different objects, so when you call `row.GetpartnerRows()`, there is no Partner data in the `usersTable` to return

Comment: @BerndLinde so, how can I connect them together? I cant understand why VS creates this method if it didnt work